# Accessing elements of webview within a native iPhone app using UI Automation

Tags: ui-automation

I am working on UI test automation using Apple's UIAutomation framework for  a native iPhone app that uses web views for its checkout transactions. The problem I am facing is that when I tap on Checkout button from the native app, a webview within the app opens up which has a button named 'Complete Checkout' that I am not able to access. I have tried using `target.logElemenTree()` to get the elements of the WebView, but I do not get to see anything in Instruments. Can anybody let me know how to access webview elements within the native app on iOS?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the X,Y coordinates of the Complete Checkout button and have UI Automation tap it. For example, if the X,Y coordinates of the button are x:10, y:20 you would run target.tap({x:10, y:20});

Answer (score 0):

If your checkout button is a link inside a webview then you will be able to access it.
check the property of the  "complete checkout". Tapping using X and Y co-ordinates is not a recommended option.